# How to get a specific duplicate values keys using hashMap in java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, set

I have this problem with my code. i created a hashMap that store file path as key and Md5 hash as values like this:

```
Key :  [C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.jpg] Valu   :  [36305b66726e9d3d8d9bbff2ec07e63b]
Key :  [C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.jpg] Value  :  [88434b1b9794feacb373048fccd901c1]
Key :  [C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.jpg] Value  :  [3743436e13b95c2e9ff46dbd8516ea48]
Key :  [C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.avi]  Value :  [416c2fe27204ce3a78abfb18963c4eb7]
Key :  [C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.jpg]  Value :  [8fd65bee3e7d26328e978cf2925c3625]
Key :  [C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.avi]  Value :  [37ba22d609b4e384c00c35ca70a1837d]
```

I only wanted it to display the duplicate values and it keys equivalence like this:

```
  Key:[C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.jpg]  Value:[f884c30bfad89a285507d4c381700583]
  Key :  [C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.jpg] Value:[f884c30bfad89a285507d4c381700583]
  Key :  [C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\.jpg]  Value:[f884c30bfad89a285507d4c381700583]
```

Here is my code, when ever i run it, it displays an null set like this:

null
   null
   null
   null

```
  Map<Set<String>, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
           try {
                for(File file : f.listFiles()){
                   //System.out.println((hashed(file)));
                        map.put(file(file),(hashed(file)));

               }

           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(DelDuplicate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,    null,   ex);
           }
          Map<Set<String>,List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
          map2.putAll(map);
           for (Map.Entry<Set<String>, List<String> > entry : map2.entrySet()) {
               //System.out.println(" Key :  " + entry.getKey() 
                                  //+ "  Value :  " + entry.getValue());

                modedHash mode = new modedHash();
               System.out.println(mode.getKeys(getDuplicate(entry.getValue())));

            }               

     }
          public class modedHash extends HashMap{
            public List<Object> getKeys(Object value){
             List<Object> keys = null;
              if(containsValue(value)){
               keys = new ArrayList<>();
                Set<String> keyset = keySet();
          for (Object key : keyset){
            if(get(key).equals(value)){
              keys.add(key);
       }
   }
  }
  return keys;
}

  public  List<String> hashed(File file) throws IOException{
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  String hash;
  if(file.exists() && file != (null)){
      //for(File f : file.listFiles()){
            hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file));
         list.add(hash);

  //}

  }
 return list;
}
     public  Set<String> file (File f){
       Set<String> list = new HashSet<>();

      if(f.exists() && f != (null)){
      //for(File file : f.listFiles()){
          list.add(f.getPath());
      // }
    }
    return list;
  }

 public static <T> List  getDuplicate(Collection<T> check){

  final List<T> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();

  Set<T> uniques = new HashSet<T>(){
    public boolean add(T e){
        if(contains(e)){
            duplicates.add(e);
        }
        return super.add(e);
    }


  };

  for(T t : check)
      uniques.add(t);

  return duplicates;
```

}

the modedHash class extends HashMap which is used to compare the actual values keys.The getDuplcate method checks the List and output only duplicates. Please your help in this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the problem is with what `getDuplicate` returns, wouldn't that code be relevant?

Comment: Please include the code for your `file` method (used in `map.put(file(file), …)`), your `modedHash.getKeys` method, and your `getDuplicate` method in your question.

Comment: @emekamba That is much better, but we still need to see the code for the `getDuplicate` method.

Comment: @VGR I have edited the post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your goal is to find files with duplicate MD5 hashes.  Since the hash is the intended unique identifier of the files, you should be using it as your key:

```
public void findDuplicateFiles(File[] files) {

    // In Java 8, the following loop can be replaced by:
    //Map<String, List<File>> filesByHash =
    //    Stream.of(files).filter(File::isFile).collect(
    //        Collectors.groupingBy(file -> MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file))));

    Map<String, List<File>> filesByHash = new HashMap<>();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            continue;
        }

        String hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file));

        List<File> filesForHash = filesByHash.get(hash);
        if (filesForHash == null) {
            filesByHash.put(hash, filesForHash = new ArrayList<File>());
        }

        filesForHash.add(file);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<File>> entry : filesByHash.entrySet()) {
        List<File> filesForHash = entry.getValue();
        if (filesForHash.size() > 1) {
            String hash = entry.getKey();
            System.out.printf("%,d files have hash %s:%n",
                filesForHash.size(), hash);

            for (File file : filesForHash) {
                System.out.println("  " + file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so so so much, you have helped me so much. You are really the best....I love you...You have solved my problem, I highly appreciate your help...Thank you.